# Scroll faster using css or javascript - parallax

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I am trying to figure out how this website does this effect :

http://rosedalelivery.com/

Can this be done using css?  I tried using multiple background images, but the scrolling effect just doesn't match up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to checkout how a website achieves something in CSS or JS is to use Chrome's Inspector tool.

You can right-click on the site's page and inspect the site's resources (cmd + option + i on Mac) -- click the resource tab. Under the scripts it shows a stellar.js which is a popular jQuery plug-in for doing parallax scrolling that's done on the website you're referencing.

The Stellar.js website: http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

Stellar.js Github page: https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js

It also looks like the site is using NiceScroll for mobile scrolling: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, appreciate it.

Comment: @user2981725 while it looks like this question has been put on hold by the moderators, if you do get part way though the process of this and can add a bit more code, you'll likely get the question opened up again.